# \wrapfigure makes my image to disappear

Tags: graphics, wrapfigure

I try to add an image with text side by side. I've googled a lot and found that the most easy way is to use the package `\wrapfigure`.

Actually, it is a mathematical school exercise with the solution and the geometry shape. I don't know if it is important, but the exercise is part of an enumerate list. I don't know why, but my image isn't there when I build the code. If I remove the wrapfigure and leave without it, then it is there but in the end of the text.

Here is a MWE:

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item ....  
    \item ....
    \item Here is some text...blah blah ... $E=E_1+E_2+E_3=2\cdot14+2\cdot3+2\cdot3=2\cdot(14+3+3)=2\cdot20=40$.

    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.4\textwidth}
        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{shape1.png}
        \end{center}
    \end{wrapfigure}
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: wrapfig.sty says   - You must not specify a wrapfigure in any type of list environment or
    or immediately before or immediately after one.  It is OK to follow
    a list if there is a blank line ("\par") in between.  (line 355)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see. Didn't know that. New to LaTeX here :)...Do you know another way to do what I need?

Comment: You can't _need_ the text to wrap:-) simplest is just to use `\includegraphics` with no surround, or if you want use a \minipage{}{some text}\includegrapics so they come side by side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based on David Carlisle's comment.

First, I turned your code into an MWE by adding the beginning and end of the file required to make it compile:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% omit the package for wrapfigure as I'm not going to use it
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

I also replace the image you used with `tiger` because this image is included in all standard TeX distributions.

Setting up the `minipage` environment, you'd put the image beside the text as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
  \noindent
    \begin{minipage}{.6\linewidth}
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item ....
        \item ....
        \item Here is some text...blah blah ... $E=E_1+E_2+E_3=2\cdot14+2\cdot3+2\cdot3=2\cdot(14+3+3)=2\cdot20=40$.
      \end{enumerate}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{.4\linewidth}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{tiger}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: tiger lists]